# sharepoint online workflow content approval doesn't send email for some reason

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-approval, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a list and i have set it to use the require content approval.
I created a workflow SP 2013 to send an email when

```
If Approval Status = "Pending"
 - Send Email
```

When i run the workflow manually or when an item is created it doesn't send an email.
But when i use SP 2010 designer workflow it works.
Why is SP 2013 designer workflow isn't sending emails. Am i missing something with the content approval with SP 2013 designer?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Is the user an external user?

If it is true, it's by default SharePoint Designer workflows creating using SharePoint 2013 Workflows will not sent emails to the external users (email addresses).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/rajbugga/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-send-emails-to-external-email-addresses-sharepoint-2013-workflows

If it is false, please add a "Log to history list" action after send emails action to track the email sending status.

**-----------------------------------------------------------Update--------------------------------------------------------------**
Use flow to monitor the approval status then send emails:

[image]

**----------------------------------------------------------Update2--------------------------------------------------------------**

If we enable content approval in the list, the default status syntax of the approval column is **2;#pending** in designer workflow:

[image]

Comment: No Julie_MSFT.It isn't am external user. See screenshot of the workflow here https://ibb.co/z5MSGfD

Comment: its seems the OTB content approval doesn't work with sharepoint workflow 2013.Can you please test this and confirm this from your end?

Comment: Per my test SharePoint designer 2013 workflow sends email successfully.Please re-publish the 2013 workflow and test again, if the issue still exists, create a new list and  check the result. If above ways not work for you, please use flow to meet your requirement, and I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thanks.I wasn't considering using power automate, Also not sure the log to workflow history isn't working either.Can you please screenshoot what exactly your workflow looks like?

Comment: Also another issue is when i approve..and refresh the approval status changed back to pending :( Not sure why

Comment: My workflow has the same steps with yours.

Comment: Thanks Julie_MSFT,. I fixed it another way. I noticed when i do in SP 2013 "If Approval Status = "Pending""
 - Send Email 
The pending value is actually 2 and normally in the workflow is showing #Pending. When i use the values 1,2,3 as the approval status in  my SP2013. The If statement validated and the send email worked. Any ideas why this is the case in SP2013?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it.